# iOS app using Firebase for user engagement

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-notifications

In an iOS app, I need to present a screen. Let's call it user engagement screen to introduce upload photo feature to users (if they tap on a button in this screen they will be directed to the upload photo screen) if they land in the photo gallery screen for more than 3 times.

Is it possible to use Firebase to present that screen? 
For example send notification to user's app in foreground  (if they have visited gallery screen more than 3 times) to present that user engagement screen?

Can I filter out the notifications to be sent to users who currently landed in screen x and have visited this screen for more than 3 times?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase allows you to create Audiences based in events or user properties. Theoretically you could create an audience of users who acceded at least 3 times to the gallery. And with Firebase you can send push notifications to users who belong to an Audience.

Unfortunately there is no way to send push notifications who users who just became member of an Audience. You have to send push notifications to all members in your audience.